# MS Access add a search form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

In Access I have some difficulties to create a search form based on a Query. The search form will be based on the title

[image]

Steps:
1. **On my query field I add this formula**

```
[Forms]![Main Menu]![SearchInput]
```

[image]

2. **I added a InputBox (SearchInput) and a Button in the Main Menu form.**

[image]

3. **I connected the Button to the Query**.

[image: enter code here]

4. `Result` 
   When I type A in the SearchInput box suppose to render all the Title that contains a A but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put this into the Criteria of the Query

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Main Menu]![SearchInput] & "*"
```

[image]